# How can I apply the same styling to multiple elements?

Tags: android

How can I appy the same properties (styling actually) to multiple elements in Android?

I know how to do it with CSS and HTML. Then you have classes. Is there an equivalent for Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your style in `res/values/styles.xml`

You can define it like that :

```
<style name="test" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

And in your layout file, if you want to use it :

```
<Button style="@style/test"/>
```

Here the button will have a green background since `#00FF00` is green

If you want all Button to have this style do like that :

```
<style name="ApplicationStyle" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/test</item>
</style>
```

You can find more informations in the manual : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html

Comment: How do I include the styling then? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

To give an example for @Johnnybossboy, building upon the subtle hints given my @Mickael B., I implemented this into my own project.

in res-values
create a new "values resource file" names styles.xml
in my styles file, I include 2 styles: one for my imageView and one for my textView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="imageView" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:layout_width">100dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="textView" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You can see that it follows a similar context but now your key-value pair is broken up so the key is now the name and the value is the inner element.

To use these new styles, you just go to the code view of any XML file in your project and add a line similar to this: `style="@style/textView"`

In my project, I replaced:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/comfortImageDescription"
    android:src="@drawable/comfort" 
/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/comfortText"
/>
```

with this:

```
<ImageView
    style="@style/imageView"
    android:contentDescription="@string/comfortImageDescription"
    android:src="@drawable/comfort" 
/>
<TextView
    style="@style/textView"
    android:text="@string/comfortText"
/>
```

In this way, I can use a similar style over an over again while still having customizable elements. I would have also implemented @Mickael B.'s second suggestion to apply a style to all of 1 element, however I have many different style types for my elements.